# Customize inline_formset field display of foreign key

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have a model called Access that links to two other models.

```
class Access (models.Model):
    portfolio_id = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    access_rights = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACCESS_CHOICES)
```

I have created this form.

```
class UserAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Access
```

I have this in the view.

```
AccessFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Portfolio,
                                      Access,
                                      form=UserAccessForm,
                                      extra=1,
                                      can_delete=False)
cAccessFormSet = AccessFormSet(instance=cPorfolio)
```

The issue is in the web page, user_id displays as a choicefield giving me a list of all my users (i.e. "jane15", "tom54").  I want it to be a text field that someone has to type in the username.  When I try to customize it as below, it displays "user ids" instead of the "username" (i.e. "1", "2").

```
class UserAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_id = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Access
```

How do I get the formset to display and accept usernames (i.e. "jane15") as a textfield instead of as a choicefield?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wanted to type in usernames, a choice field is not the way to go.

Use a `CharField` which is a `<input type='text'>` and override the `clean_FOO` method to validate the input into a user instance or raise an error message.

```
class UserAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_id = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Access

    def clean_user_id(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('user_id')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=data)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("No user exists by that username")
        return user
```

Pass that into your formset and you're done.

Comment: That is what I have already tried. That causes my users to be displayed as their user IDs instead of their user names.  For security reasons, I need usernames and without the drop down list.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can override the add functionality but when viewing the data, the actual table field only has a number.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem.  How can I get around that?

Comment: I tried creating a custom widget that has its own format_value method / value_from_datadict, but it fails at the end because this goes through  model validation with the new value. I think the answer is somewhere in the widget rendering.. i'll keep experimenting